# Registration only site with custom policy

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a task to create registration only custom policy. So I need a page to pick local account or different social provider. And after the user will be navigate to the proper registration site. I can manage this by standard policies, but I have to do this job with custom policies. Are there any was to do such think with custom policies? I didn't find any registration only reference in the starter pack....

rgds,
'child

Answer (score 0):

This is covered [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-identity-provider).

You can have as many IDP as you want.

The first step of the user journey will then have as many ClaimsProviderSelections as you require. This example is for adding Azure AD.

```
<ClaimsProviderSelections>
    ...
    <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="AzureADContosoExchange" />
</ClaimsProviderSelections>
```

**Update**

Also, look in the B2C starter pack.

```
<UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignIn">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
      
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="FacebookExchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- Check if the user has selected to sign in using one of the social providers -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="FacebookExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Facebook-OAUTH" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
```

You'll see there are two "ClaimsProviderSelection", one for local accounts and one for Facebook.

Comment: I'm not fully get u, could you please explain your answer in deatils? Thanks!